# innerHTML not working with more than one eventListener in Javascript "Type Ahead" code

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, addeventlistener

I am working through the Wes Box Javascript30 course and am making my own additions to the "Type Ahead" code. The original code takes in a single data source and, with an eventListener, updates the search suggestions by returning list elements in template literals and updating the results with innerHTML as the user types in the input. I have modified the code to search over another set of data, but now I cannot get the "type ahead" feature to update the suggestions properly.

Since I am focusing on building pure Javascript knowledge, I am not using any libraries to write this. I have tried several different techniques, most found on here, that I can't get to work properly.

This one (the answer with the most upvotes) suggests using insertAdjacentHTML(). The problem with this in my code is that the results that matched with less letters are never filtered out, so in the end there is a long list of results that no longer fit the input.

[Javascript - Append HTML to container element without innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304453/javascript-append-html-to-container-element-without-innerhtml)

I have tried using a combination of createElement and appendChild but again, I can't get the results to filter out the matches that no longer apply. I referenced this previous question but can't work out the problem from the answer that was accepted here.

[Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object when trying to append basic html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277713/argument-1-of-node-appendchild-is-not-an-object-when-trying-to-append-basic-html)

I also read about security considerations about using innerHTML in your code listed in this reference from MDN. I know this is only practice and will never be published on the web, but I stay away from using it?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

The "data" here is just a sample but works the same way as the data I am using. This is just a way to shorten it. (I cannot combine the data, like it may appear below - this is very simplified to save space)

```
<form class="search-form">
    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search">
    <ul class="suggestions"></ul>
</form>

<script>
const arr1 = ['pink','blue','green','purple'];
const arr2 = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black'];

function displayArr1() {
  const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, arr1)
  const html = matchArray.map(item => {
      const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
      const itemName = item.replace(regex, `<span class='hl'>${this.value}</span>`);
return `
  <li>
    <span class='name'>${itemName}</span>
  </li>
  `;
 }).join('');
 suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}

function findMatches(wordToMatch, arr) {
    return arr.filter(item => {
        const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        return item.match(regex);
    });
}

function displayArr2() {
  const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, arr2)
  const html = matchArray.map(item => {
      const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
      const itemName = item.replace(regex, `<span class='hl'>${this.value}</span>`);
return `
  <li>
    <span class='name'>${itemName}</span>
  </li>
  `;
 }).join('');
 suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}

const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayArr1);
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayArr2);
</script>
```

Same code in JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/slawk/25bt8edw/

This works fine with only one of the eventListeners (whichever one is on the bottom). I know that the problem is that when using innerHTML you add to/destroy the elements, which removes the eventListeners. I need a solution that allows me to display suggestions from both "data sources" at once as the user types. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you want to combine both arrays you could use [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) but if you also want to remove duplicated value you need to create a new function such as being explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items).

To implement it you can use:

```
function arrayUnique(array) {
  var a = array.concat();
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
      if (a[i] === a[j])
        a.splice(j--, 1);
    }
  }

  return a;
}
var array3 = arrayUnique(arr1.concat(arr2));
```

See [jsFiddle Fork](https://jsfiddle.net/L0qov3s5/) or snippet for example.

```js
const arr1 = ['pink', 'blue', 'green', 'purple'];
const arr2 = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black'];

function arrayUnique(array) {
  var a = array.concat();
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
      if (a[i] === a[j])
        a.splice(j--, 1);
    }
  }

  return a;
}
var array3 = arrayUnique(arr1.concat(arr2));

function displayArr() {
  const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, array3)
  const html = matchArray.map(item => {
    const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
    const itemName = item.replace(regex, `<span class='hl'>${this.value}</span>`);
    return `
      <li>
        <span class='name'>${itemName}</span>
      </li>
      `;
  }).join('');
  suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}

function findMatches(wordToMatch, arr) {
  return arr.filter(item => {
    const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
    return item.match(regex);
  });
}

const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayArr);
```

```html
<form class="search-form">
  <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search">
  <ul class="suggestions"></ul>
</form>
```